# I have a Kubernetes Deployment and Service working, but my Ingress somehow only shows up talking to port 80 no matter what

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster that I'm working to get going on https load balancing.

So far I have:

- deployment
- service (x 2 -- see below)
- ingress
- SSL cert -- google managed version

All of these seem to be working, but I'm getting a 502 error when connecting to the hostname via https:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

When trying to trace this down I found [a debugging post](https://cameron-manavian.medium.com/how-to-debug-a-502-on-kubernetes-c2b0bc1f7490) but when combing through it I found that his ingress shows ports **80,443** ... while I can never get mine to show anything but port **80**.

This is even after I split my service into two different services, one on port 443 and one on port 80, and now am only telling the ingress about the 443 service and it **still** shows up with just port 80 and I'm **still** getting the 502 error.

The YAML for the deployment (asked by the commenter below):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: gcr.io/myapp-dev/myapp-container:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

The YAML for the '443 service':

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service443
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
```

And the Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    # If the class annotation is not specified it defaults to "gce".
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "kubething"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: clearspring-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: my-service443
      port:
        name: https
```

I don't understand (a) why the ingress is showing only port 80 and why I'm still getting 502 errors.

Thanks much for any help whatsoever!

Comment: Could you also post your pod configuration? GCE ingress is sensitive in the service accessibility. If GCP cannot reach the service successfully, it will screw up without obvious error.

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl describe managedcertificate clearspring-cert`?
It can take a while to provision the managed cert.

Comment: I understand that; it takes 15 minutes but that isn't the problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was missing readiness and liveness probes; when I changed the deployment like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cleardev-deployment
  labels:
    app: clearspring
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: clearspring
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: clearspring
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: clearspring
        image: gcr.io/clearspring-dev/clearspring-container:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
```

Then the status changed from **UNHEALTHY** to **Unknown** ... but I was still getting the 502 error.

The liveness probe did its job: the procedure was not running on port 8080 on all hosts, just on 127.0.0.1. I fixed that ... still not working but tried **EXPOSE 8080** in the Dockerfile and now I guess I need to look at firewall rules because liveness/readiness probes can't connect.

Note that I had to delete and recreate the cluster to get this far ... I think. I just tried first updating the deployment and I didn't get any change from **UNHEALTHY**.